# How to enter alternative characters from extended keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, special-characters, compose-key

I have installed Russian(Kazakhstan, with Kazakh) input source. How do I type the alternative(neighbour) character in this layout?
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PMh1.png) is the screenshot of layout.
By default it types the characters on the left side of the button, and I need to type on the right side sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most keyboard layouts with 3rd and 4th level symbols include this line:

```
include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

which by default makes <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd> a key for accessing such symbols as soon as the user switches to the layout.

The *Russian (Kazakhstan, with Kazakh)* keyboard layout uses a different method, which may make it necessary to define a 3rd level key explicitly. To do that:

- Install the `gnome-tweaks` package (if not already installed)
- Open *Tweaks*, navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose the 3rd level*, and select a key of your choice.